# What is the difference in '->' between struct node and struct node*?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am new to pointers and there is this code for merge sort of linked lists. And here it has declared a dummy node as `struct node dummy;` and the next node for dummy node is NULL so to set it we use `dummy.next = NULL;`.

```
/* Link list node */
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node* SortedMerge(struct node* a, struct node* b) 
{
   /* a dummy first node to hang the result on */   
   struct node dummy;      

   /* tail points to the last result node  */
   struct node* tail = &dummy;  

   /* so tail->next is the place to add new nodes 
     to the result. */
   dummy.next = NULL;
//Code continues...
}
```

I understand that i can use it if it was `struct node *dummy;`
but we cant use it here as it is not a pointer node.
So my question is why doesn't `dummy->next = NULL` work here?
and what is the difference between struct node and struct node* ??

Comment: Dummy is not a pointer, so `->` doesn't work. `->` is for pointers only.

Comment: So basically you ask difference between pointer and a normal variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a -> b` is shorthand for `(*a).b`.

If `a` is not a pointer, `*a` is not valid, and neither is `a -> b`.

Answer (score 2):

`dummy` is not a pointer to a structure. It is the structure variable itself. 
You can derefer attributes of a structure with the operator `->` only if it is a pointer to the structure.

If you are using the struct variable, then `.` is the way to go about, which is very much the case with `dummy`.

Answer (score 1):

> I  understand that i can use it if it was `struct node *dummy;`

If by "it" you mean `struct node dummy;` then the answer is no. You cannot use a pointer to `node` in the same way as a pointer to `node`.

> So my question is why doesn't `dummy->next = NULL` work here?

Because `dummy` is a `node`, not a pointer, and operator `->` if for pointers. The expression `dummy->next` has the same semantics as `(*dummy).next`.

Answer (score 1):

> . So my question is why doesn't dummy->next = NULL work here? and what is the difference between struct node and struct node* ?

Declared as this `struct node dummy;`

`dummy->next=NULL` doesn't work because `dummy` is not a pointer to struct .

If you write so -

```
struct node A;  // then A is a struct variable which can access struct members  using '.' operator
```

and this -

```
struct node* B; // then B is a pointer to struct node which can access struct member using '->`  or like this (*B).data=something.
```